# Oracle direct load insert of 54,061,487 records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, append

I have a direct load insert of 54,061,487 records. I'm looking for speed.  I do not need to rollback at all.

All tables involved are set to `NOLOGGING`.

Here's one way to do this

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE meRegionsNow';
...

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meRegionsNow(
   carrierId     ,
   region        ,
   zip           ,
   side          ,
   subPlanTypeId ,
   monthIn       )
   SELECT
      r.carrierId     as carrierId     ,
      r.region        as region        ,
      r.zip           as zip           ,
      r.side          as side          ,
      r.subPlanTypeId as subPlanTypeId ,
      t.monthIn       as monthIn
   FROM
      meTimeline t
         INNER JOIN region r
         ON t.monthIn >= r.effective AND
            t.monthIn <= r.expiry;
```

The execution plan for this is as expected (using the right 
indexes to speed up the join):

```
 Statement Id=5336   Type=  
 Cost=2.64022111505165E-308  TimeStamp=25-10-11::15::35:08  

   (1)  SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS   
 Est. Rows: 5,667  Cost: 483  
   (5)  TABLE TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID SCHEMA.REGION  [Analyzed]   
   (5)   Blocks: 2,826 Est. Rows: 944 of 377,779  Cost: 80   
 Tablespace: USERS  
       (4)  NESTED LOOPS   
            Est. Rows: 5,667  Cost: 483  
           (2)  INDEX INDEX FULL SCAN SCHEMA.METL$MONTHIN  [Analyzed]   
                Est. Rows: 6  Cost: 1  
           (3)  INDEX INDEX RANGE SCAN SCHEMA.RGN$MULTI3  [Analyzed]   
                Est. Rows: 944  Cost: 72
```

Here's another way to do this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE meRegionsNow';
...

DECLARE
   CURSOR meTimeline_cur IS
      SELECT monthIn
      FROM meTimeline
      ORDER BY monthIn;
BEGIN
   FOR meTimeline_rec IN meTimeline_cur LOOP
      /* Cross regions with timeline */
      INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meRegionsNow(
         carrierId     ,
         region        ,
         zip           ,
         side          ,
         subPlanTypeId ,
         monthIn       )
         SELECT
            r.carrierId            as carrierId     ,
            r.region               as region        ,
            r.zip                  as zip           ,
            r.side                 as side          ,
            r.subPlanTypeId        as subPlanTypeId ,
            meTimeline_rec.monthIn as monthIn
         FROM region r
         WHERE
            meTimeline_rec.monthIn >= r.effective AND
            meTimeline_rec.monthIn <= r.expiry;
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

What is the fastest way? I don't think there's much difference between cursor controlled direct load insert  and the straight SQL direct load insert.

Again, I don't care about logging, rolling back, keeping any undo data. I suspect that the reason this is taking long is that the tablespace data file is auto extending too frequently using default extents that are too small in size.

I'm thinking this problem will be solved as soon as I resize the `meRegionsNow` tablespace
datafile.

Comment: 54M rows is a lot to get from an index. The explain plan you posted only estimates 5667 rows will be returned - is this a test database? You may find the plan changes to full scan and hash join on the full dataset, and that may be better. I'd also look at making indexes on the target table unusable before the load and then rebuild, and also use parallel insert and parallel select (note to get parallel insert working you need to do 'alter session enable parallel dml'.

Comment: @Stephen The statement in question is part of a stored procedure and this stored procedure usually runs with 1/15 of the data volume that I'm trying to run through it this one time. I believe the library cache has a stored execution plan for the common case -- this is why it grossly underestimates the data volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is likely to be faster because it has fewer context switches between the PL/SQL engine and the SQL engine. You can easily find out by trying both methods.

Comment: @Klaus I had not thought of the context switch between the engines. I think you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a parallelize the load using the parallel hint? (you may find that you need to remove/invalidate constraints & indexes during the load then turn them back on after the load)

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL*/ INTO meRegionsNow( ..... 
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL*/ .....
```

there are lots of prerequsits for parallel & direct loads to work....

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604
see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16541/parallel003.htm#VLDBG1455

Comment: The complex prerequisites are the reason I haven't gone to parallel. It's the KIS principle.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding the data with commits between blocks should reduce the amount of temporary table space usage so it would likely be a lot more reliable if temp tablespace is limited.

OTOH the sharded approach has to access the source tables multiple times - but since the non-sharded approach seems to be using exclusively indexed lookups on the table it will have little impact on performance (if there had been full table scans on the single pass approach, sharding would likely have been a lot slower).